# Can an application field become null?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

In my Android app I have set a custom Application-derived class. In it I have a member field to store some arbitrary object in.

So I have:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

public static MyApp mInstance;
public Object mData;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
   mInstance = this;
}

public void setData(Object data) {
    mData = data;
}

public Object getData() { return mData; } 

}
```

Now in one `Activity` I'm doing

```
public doSetData() {

     someMyData = ....
     MyApp.mInstance.setData(someMyData);

}
```

In another `Activity` I'm doing

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle) {

     Object myDataRetrieved = MyApp.mInstance.getData();

}
```

I can see that sometimes `myDataRetrieved` is `null`. However, I believe I have never passed `null` in `MyApp.setData()`. Of course, I can be wrong.

Yet, can there be such circumstances under which `MyApp.mData` becomes null by itself?

Comment: What it returns when u use getData() instead of referring it directly....

Comment: Ah, I always use getData, is there any difference? I've edited as such

Comment: If the Activity is destroyed, you will lose all your fields values. If you want to use data from Activity A in Activity B, pass it with an Intent.

Comment: To Access your application you need to do like this MyApp app = (MyApp) getApplication(); and to get data you need to use app.getData()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yet, can there be such circumstances under which MyApp.mData becomes null by itself?

Sure. It will happen every time Android terminates the process, which will happen when your app is not in the foreground, Android needs RAM, and your app is next in line to be terminated.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand. Could you, please, advise what would be a good way to always have those data of mine available? Do I have to persist them?

Comment: @Alex: "Do I have to persist them?" -- yes. Use static data members and custom `Application` classes solely as caches.

Answer (score 0):

You can never guarantee that your data will be retained in memory, since the system can always reap the process to reclaim resources.

Thus, your application must *always* be prepared to save any persistent data either in [onSaveInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) (short term) or in [onPause()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) (long term), and then retrieve it in onCreate().

That said, there's also the "singleton pattern" which I'm quite fond of.  This is a software design pattern in which you create a special class just to hold your persistent data.  There's only ever once instance of the class (thus the name "singleton") which is created on demand the first time your data is needed.  The singleton is retained so that any subsequent needs for the persistent data just use the same object without the need to re-load the data from long-term storage.  As long as the system doesn't reap your process, the data is always there with nearly zero cost to access.  If the system *does* reap your process, the data is transparently re-loaded, and your application never notices the difference.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779357/338479 for my implementation of a singleton.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how a singleton differs from a custom Application class. Custom Application class  is also a singleton. You mean I can avoid persisting my data somehow? It's not that those data always stay the same.

Comment: Custom application classes can do exactly the same thing.  I've used them as well.  It's all a matter of personal preference.

Comment: strictly speaking it doesn't matter which class you make into your singleton.

Answer (score 0):

just save your data and load it up on application object creation if the instance was destroyed, which will always be created before the activity.

if you minimize the memory use then it will survive longer in the android zygote before beig purged.   saveinstancestate etc are good only for small data blocks. sharing data through app instance is ok and sometimes recommended, however it is not different from using static fields. same constraints apply.

if you want minimal memory use then using the parcels etc to save your data is not recommended, not even by google.